# Programming Arduino with FTDI via Tx and Rx pins

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-leonardo

How program Arduino with a FTDI cable/breakout_board via pins 0 (Rx) and 1 (Tx)?

In case the USB to UART chip (16U2 or other) is broken, you can program Arduino with a FTDI instead of 16U2 or other chip.

What are the connections to reset the Arduino microcontroller automatically when sketch is upload?

Comment: has your FTDI a DTR pin?

Comment: Yes, DTR and CTS pins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same as for a breadboard Arduino.  That is, connect the DTR pin of your breakout board through a 0.1uF capacitor to the RESET pin. TX and RX then connect to the RX and TX pins of the Arduino respectively, along with of course the ground connection.